# Laravel Routes and middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a middleware copied from `https://gist.github.com/amochohan/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246

```
Route::get('user/{user}', [
 'middleware' => ['auth', 'roles'],
 'uses' => 'UserController@index',
 'roles' => ['administrator', 'manager']
]);
```

My routes

how do I add the roles to the resources

```
Route::resource('user','UserController')->middleware(['auth','roles']);;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without digging into how Resource Routes are registered from the Registrar you can just wrap this in a route group and set the roles:

```
Route::group(['roles' => ['admin', ...], function () {
    Route::resource(..., ...);
});
```

All routes are registered individually; Route groups are a means to cascade configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That's wrong way to put it... You don't add the roles to the resources, that roles middleware needs to exist under app/Http/Middleware/Roles.php

and then inside that class you make your logic...

This is just a pseudocode but you should understand it:

```
class Roles
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(! in_array(auth()->user()->role, $roles)) {
           return redirect()->back()->with('alert', 'Access Denied! Action not allowed.');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

And to pass the roles to the middleware you should read more about this in the official docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#middleware-parameters

And this is copied from some blog article:

```
Route::get('/some-url',['middleware'=>'roles:admin, editor', function () {
     return "Access is granted for this operation";
 
}]);
```

and in Roles Middleware handle function

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, ...$params)
{
 
    print_r($params);
 
    exit;
 
    return $next($request);
}
```

$params should return the array of roles ['admin', 'editor']